# difference between a sturgian shock troop and a veteran warrior, bannerlord

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

they both upgrade from the sturgian spearmen, use one-handed axes and shields, and look pretty similar. What is the difference? thier names imply that the veteran warrior would be better armored, and the shock troop faster, but I don't know wether that is actually the case. Can you please tell me the difference between a shock troop and a veteran warrior, or if they do the same thing and one is just better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click the troop's icon to jump straight into the in-game glossary of the troop's stats and their "evolution trees".

Hovering the mouse over each possible promotion type should show you the stats of the resultant troop.

(I'm not at a computer that can run Bannerlord at the moment so I can't add the exact numbers to this answer for... {checks clock} another 74 minutes, but generally when there's a branch it usually means one side is going to go into ranged weaponry while the other focuses on melee, or one side will wind up becoming mounted if you have horses for them.)

**EDIT** I'm off the clock, on Bannerlord, and here are the stats (as of 27/05/2020; the game is still in early access so patches and changes may occur):

**Shock Troop**:

```
1H 140
2H 60
Polearm 140
Bow 75
Crossbow 15
Throwing 30
Riding 45
Athletics 130
```

**Veteran**

```
1H 130
2H 80
Polearm 80
Bow 60
Crossbow 20
Throwing 130
Riding 60
Athletics 130
```

Given that neither of these gets a horse, the main differences are that the shock troops are better at melee combat with their swords and pikes, while the veterans will get much more mileage out of their throwing axes.

Comment: you should look at their gear too, shock troop armor is half the value of the veteran armor I believe